# Zapier: Task timed out after 1.00 seconds

Tags: javascript, zapier

I am using the Zapier Code application in the javascript language, I am making a request in an api but in almost all attempts at the time of executing the script, I get the error message: "We had trouble sending your test through. Please try again. Error: 
2018-03-09T14:32:54.748Z c0958e0a-23a6-11e8-9be1-a515bc24f853 Task timed out after 1.00 seconds". Sometimes script execution happens successfully, but most of the time it gives this error.

The calling code in the api I'm using is this:

```
var promises = [];
var retornoDaChamada;
promises.push(fetch(urls));

Promise.all(promises).then(function(res){
    var blobPromises = [];
    for (var i = res.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        blobPromises.push(res[i].text());
    }
    return Promise.all(blobPromises);
}).then(function(body){
    retornoDaChamada=JSON.parse(body);
    var titulosDaApi = [retornoDaChamada.length];
    var duracao = [retornoDaChamada.length];
    var ids = [retornoDaChamada.length];
    for(var i=0; i<retornoDaChamada.length; i++){
      titulosDaApi[i]=retornoDaChamada[i].title;
      duracao[i]=milissegundosParaHorasMinutosSegundos(retornoDaChamada[i].files[0].fileInfo.duration);
      ids[i]=retornoDaChamada[i].id;
    }

    var output = {titulosDaApi, duracao, ids};
    callback(null, output);

}).catch(callback);
```

I read the documentation of the application Code and I kind of understood that free user only has the time of up to 1 second for calls in Api, is there any way I can get around this problem even though I am a free user?

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

It's a little tough to understand the context of your code, but it looks like you're doing multiple HTTP requests. Due to their nature, they're a very slow operation. If you're doing more than 1 (maybe two if the external resource responds really quickly), you're unlikely to be able to fit everything into 1 second.

Sorry for the bad news!

Comment: In fact I only make a single call in the api, I only pass a single URL to get a JSon with the data, and every once in a while the response occurs with less than 1 second.

Comment: If that's the case, then you're at the mercy of how fast the external resource can respond. That, or upgrading to a paid plan are probably your only options. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Thank you! I am aware that trying to resolve via Api's call in the code application will not work, I am studying the possibility of solving this problem using Zapier's Webhooks, I am trying to understand the operation.